# How to store json data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

This code works perfectly for parsing the json object, but I need to store all json data to mysql. How can I retrieve the value to store in mysql?

```
function getDataAsArray($filename){
    $dataArray=array();
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $first_split=explode("}}{",$contents);
    $json_array=explode("\n",$first_split[0]);
    foreach($json_array as $value){
        $data = json_decode($value, true);
        $dataArray[]=$data;
    }
    return $dataArray;
}
$logDataArray=getDataAsArray("akshara.txt");
echo "<pre>";print_r($logDataArray); echo "</pre>"
```

Comment: did you try to use the json_decode before you explode the array ?

Comment: What's inside `$contents`? Is it a json string?

Comment: And what's this strange `"}}{"` split-separator?

Comment: actually $contents having a multiple json object each object i think opens whith flower brace and close with flower braces na ..

Comment: so i user explode method..

Comment: just let me know how to retreiv the value to store in mysql\

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL supports a JSON datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) in 2015, much like Postgres has had for a good few years now. You can simply insert the JSON into your database.

```
$json = file_get_contents($file); // {"my_value": "my data"}
DB::query("INSERT INTO my_table (json) VALUES ('{$json}')");
```

You can then use [the various JSON functions](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-lab-release-json-functions-part-2-querying-json-data/) to query your inserted data.

```
SELECT JSN_EXTRACT(json, '$.my_value') AS my_value FROM my_table // my_value = my data
```